HTMX: How to sync hx-swap transition with polled hx-get
I have a webpage that consists of a grid of items. This grid must update itself (and the items within) every three seconds which I am doing with a hx-trigger as seen below:
<body>
  <div class="grid" hx-get="/boxes" hx-trigger="every 3s">>
    <div class="itemcontainer" </div>
  </div>
</body>

Within each item there is a button which when clicked removes the item from the grid with a fade out transition. This is accomplished with a hx-swap as seen below:
HTML:
  <div class="itemcontainer">
    <div class="buttoncontainer">
      <div class="rejectbuttoncontainer">
        <a class="rejectbutton" hx-target="closest .itemcontainer" hx-swap="outerHTML swap:1s" hx-delete="/delete/{{ id }}">DELETE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
CSS:
 .itemcontainer.htmx-swapping {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  }

I have both the removal and the polling update working fine. The issue is that the polled hx-get request sometimes interrupts the transition (polled request occurs during the 1s ease out). I tried using hx-sync but can't get it to work and am not sure its possible because it seems hx-swap only sends the actual request after the delay not at the start of the delay. Is there any way I can get the polled request to wait for the delete transition to finish before updating the grid?

hx-sync should work. Can you share the code you tried that didn't work?

@McPherson I tried adding all the hx-sync="this:queue" variations to the grid div. I also tried adding hx-sync="closest .grid queue" on the reject button, but no luck.

Add hx-sync=".itemcontainer:abort" on the div with .grid class.
